# Create multiple records with a loop in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have a class Shift and a form to create a new shift. I want to be able to create many shifts at once, back-to-back so that in the form I only have to choose a date and a start time and how many shift should be created. A shift is 30 minutes long.

I now have a custom controller method that calls the create method within a loop determined by the param :block that the user chooses. I have now stopped getting error messages, but it turn I don't know what happens when I submit the form, which seems to be nothing. My question is: how can I modify my create_block method so that it does what I want?

Shifts_controller:

```
  def create
    @shift = Shift.new(shift_params)
    if @shift.save
      #redirect_to shifts_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def create_block
    start = params[:start_time]
    stop = params[:start_time] + 30.minutes
    block = params[:block]
    for number in 1..block do
      Shift.create(date:params[:date], start_time:start, stop_time:stop)
      start = stop
      stop = stop + 30.minutes
    end
    redirect_to shifts_url
  end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @shift, :url => create_block_path(@shift) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>


<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Datum %>
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Börjar %>
    <%= f.time_select :start_time, {minute_step: 30} %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :Antal %>
    <%= f.select :block, options_for_select(1..10) %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :shifts do
  member do
    patch 'book/' => 'shifts#book', as: 'book'
    patch 'un_book/' => 'shifts#un_book', as: 'un_book'
  end
end
get 'shifts/:id/book' => 'shifts#book'
get 'shifts/:id/un_book' => 'shifts#un_book'
match '/shifts/new' => 'shifts#new', as: 'create_block', via: [:post]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes are routing the `create_block` action to `ShiftsController#new`.  You need to route it to `ShiftsController#create_block`.

Try:

```
resources :shifts do
  member do
    patch 'book/' => 'shifts#book', as: 'book'
    patch 'un_book/' => 'shifts#un_book', as: 'un_book'
  end
  collection do
    post 'create_block' => 'shifts#create_block', as: 'create_block'
  end
end
get 'shifts/:id/book' => 'shifts#book'
get 'shifts/:id/un_book' => 'shifts#un_book'
```

Comment: I'd add in that in the OP's example he's trying to call a `post :new` and that's "off the Rails". `New` already has a conventional meaning--preparing a single object for later creation.  I think your answer is a great one.  I will also add, I don't know why the two gets at the end aren't members of the shifts resource.

Comment: @jaydel, I agree with everything you say.  The two routes at the end are already members of the `:shifts` route block as patches.  I left them alone in my answer to clarify the one important change for `create_block`, and because I assumed they are there for testing.